# select one checkbox from multiple MAIN Checkboxes,accordingly enable the child checkboxes in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="chkMain" />
<p><input type="checkbox" id="chkmain1" />
<p><input type="checkbox" id="chkmain2" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk1" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk2" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk3" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk4" disabled="true" />
<input class="child" type="checkbox" id="chk5" disabled="true" />

$(function(){
 $("#chkMain").click ( function() {
 if( !$(this).is ( ":checked" ) )
    {
      $(".child").attr ( "disabled" , true );
    }

    else
    {
      $(".child").removeAttr ( "disabled" );
    }
  });
});
```

this works for chkmain,n enables the child checkboxes.
what if i want to select chekmain1,n want to enable child checkbox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ID's of the parent boxes to haev a capitalized M i.e:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain2" />
```

Then use the function below:

```
$(function(){  
        $("input[id^=chkMain]").click ( function() {  
            if( !$(this).is ( ":checked" ) ){       
                $(".child").attr ( "disabled" , true );     
            }      
            else{       
                $(".child").removeAttr ( "disabled" );     
            }   
        }); 
    });
```

EDIT: Fixed a typo. Changed input[id^=chkmain] to input[id^=chkMain]

Comment: @cybernate :the above code only works when chkmain is checked n enables the child chkboxes, What if i want to check on chkbox1 then enable the child boxes,or check on chkbox2 then enable the child boxes.

Comment: it should work like this : click on chkmain -> enable child box OR click on chkmain2-> enable child box OR click on chkmain3->enable childbox

Comment: only works for chkMain.. dosent work for chkMain1 and chkMain2

Comment: Did you read my note on changing the id's to as follows(Capitalizing M in chkmain2 and chkmain1): <input type="checkbox" id="chkMain" /> <input type="checkbox" id="chkMain1" /> <input type="checkbox" id="chkMain2" /

Comment: will the above function code work for chkMain1 and chkMain2 ??? i tried,it dosn't work...

Comment: I have added the code to jsfiddle.net. Check this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/epJMs/